# sed: add leading zero to zip codes

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to add leading zeros to zip codes that have 4 digits -- I need to use the `sed` command since this is part of some training. My code below seems to keep failing, but I can't find anything wrong with it.

I'm not very familiar with Unix/Bash or `sed`, so any help with an explanation would be greatly appreciated!

```
sed -r 's/\<[0-9]{4}\>/0&/'
```

This is the error I get when the test script is run to ensure my results are ok:

```
Expected:
[['12963' '40']
 ['09993' '12']
 ['99993' '1']
 ['01003' '1234']]
Received:
[['12963' '40']
 ['9993' '12']
 ['99993' '1']
 ['1003' '1234']]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it's failing? (Does it give an error? If so, what is the *exact* text of that error? Does it just sit there? If so, how are you feeding it input?)

Comment: Also, can you provide an example of the input you're testing with? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, inasmuch as only a `sed`-based answer is acceptable, this arguably *isn't a bash question at all*, as `sed` is not built into, distributed with, or otherwise part of bash.

Comment: What kind of question is it then?

The "fail" is more that it doesn't pass the training program check, though it seems to work otherwise.

Comment: A sed question. If you're asking about standard POSIX sed, then that makes it also a generic UNIX question; if you're asking about a specific operating system's implementation of sed, then it's a question about that operating system.

Comment: ...and if you're being tested on a specific operating system, then we probably *do* need to know which one it is. An answer that's good on modern GNU sed or BSD sed won't necessarily help you if your school tests your answers on Solaris 9.

Comment: This is just Windows 7 and I'm using Git Bash. Does that help?

Comment: Hmm. I *think* git bash ships msys userland tools, but I'm actually not quite sure which `sed` it comes with. Which is to say -- it's a start.

Comment: That said, you're saying your code doesn't "pass the training program check". If you're able to run that check on your own machine, *add it to your question* so folks can test their answers!

Comment: Hmm. Reading the msys documentation, it looks like you've probably got GNU sed. If it *is* GNU sed, then `sed --version` will show the version it is in full.

Comment: GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: To be clear -- if you just say you want to add "leading zeros to zip codes", that's *a different question from* adding leading zeros to zip codes in a CSV file. **Including all the information necessary to understand when an answer is correct is essential to getting a good answer promptly**; you've wasted a lot of codeforester's time, sagunms's time, and my time by not specifying early on that your answer needed to be for CSV-format input, with GNU sed, and providing a sample piece of the input file (and corresponding output per the MCVE page) *as part of the question itself*.

Comment: Apologies, but this is literally the third or fourth time I've used Unix/Bash for coding so I'm not aware of all the necessary inputs. My problem is that the code I have works when I call the file, but it keeps failing the test. And, were this not something for work, I'd share the input file, but I'm afraid of getting into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you are piping the stdin output from commands such as an `echo` or `cat`.

```
echo '4121' | sed -r 's/[0-9]{4}/0&/' # Output: 04121
echo 'h3llo41world' | sed -r 's/[0-9]{4}/0&/' # Output: h3llo41world
echo 'h3llo4121world' | sed -r 's/[0-9]{4}/0&/' # Output: h3llo04121world
echo '1341' | sed -r 's/\<[0-9]{4}\>/0&/' # Output: 01341
echo 'a1341' | sed -r 's/\<[0-9]{4}\>/0&/' # Output: a1341
```

`-r` means Extended regular expression.

`[0-9]{4}` means you are finding four digits in your string

`0&` means add a zero and replace the ampersand `&` with whatever match you found in the left hand side.

`\<` and `\>` are word-boundary conditions. So, in example 4 above, regex matches but in example 5, regex doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

I think you intended to use `\(` and `\)` to capture the matched part, instead of `\<` and `\>`.  Since you have only one matching part, `&` would suffice here.

It's better to make your `sed` more resilient - it shouldn't misbehave when the zip code has 5 digits already:

```
echo 95014 | sed -E 's/^[0-9]{4}$/0&/' => 95014
echo 5014  | sed -E 's/^[0-9]{4}$/0&/' => 05014
```

The above `sed` expression looks for strings that have only 4 digits, as we have used the `^` (beginning of string) and `$` (end of string) anchors.

---

The limitation of the above `sed` command is that it would do the `0` padding only when your string has 4 digits.  You need to add additional expressions to handle the case of 3, 2, and 1 digit zip codes.

Comment: Strangely this doesn't seem to work. What is the `-E` supposed to do?

Comment: `-E` stands for extended regex.  Please paste the error you are getting.  It works for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: `-E` is a BSD extension that GNU also supports (whereas GNU's native flag to enable ERE is `-r`), but it's non-POSIX, so while availability is wide, it's not unlimited.

Comment: It works if I do your command lines, but I'm trying to do it against a CSV where the first columns are the zip. When I run your code it doesn't add the leading zeros.

Comment: @vashts85, please provide a sample of that CSV as part of the question.

Comment: I appreciate the update, but note that the OP probably used `\<` and `\>` for unambiguous matching in lines containing additional data (not shown in the question), irrespective of any capture groups.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sed 4.3 made `-E` finally [official](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_002dE)!

Comment: ... [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/?id=8b65e07904384b529a464c89f3739d2e7e4d5135) – and apparently `-E` has also been accepted into [POSIX sed](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528).

Comment: Uh, `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries in some dialects of regex.  Removing the boundary condition will create false positives if the input is less regular (i.e. there can be numbers among other text on a line, only some of which are ZIP codes).